# Calling new on an object using closures in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, new-operator

When calling new on an object that is utilizing closures, from what I understand the closure is setup at instantiation where private variables will be static properties of the 'class'.

Ex:

```
var testClass=(function(){
  var self={...properties...};
  return function(){
    return {
        someFunc: (function(){
          var self={...other properties...}
          return {
            self: self
          };
        }())
    };
  };
}());

var newObject=new testClass();
```

So if I need someFunc instances to be stored as a property of testClass can I use the above syntax? Will 'var self' within someFunc be instantiated each time a new testClass instance is created or will the closure be a one time deal where across all instances instanceA.someFunc.self == instanceB.someFunc.self if instanceA = new testClass(); and instanceB = new testClass();

Hope this makes sense. I havent tested it yet to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't even work properly.  Here's what will happen:

The outer IIFE will run upon code initialization.  This will establish the:

```
var self = {...};
```

once and then the variable `testClass` will contain your inner object.

Then, you will do:

```
var newObject=new testClass();
```

and get an error because testClass is an object, not a constructor function.  The exact error in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6pyx5a6n/) is:  `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`.

---

**Edit: now that you've changed the code.**

The topmost `var self= {...}` will only be instantiated once when the outer IIFE runs.  It will be common to all instances of `testClass()`.  That's because the outer IIFE only runs once and the variables created in it become part of a closure that all instances of the inner function (which becomes your actual constructor) then share.

The inner `self` (the one in `someFunc()`) will be created separately each time `obj.someFunc()` is called and within `someFunc()` the locally declared one will override the higher level `self` and you will not be able to access the higher level one from within `someFunc`.

I generally consider it a bad practice to use the same variable name in a local scope that is already defined in a higher level parent scope because it offers you no useful features and is only an opportunity for total confusion or deception about what is really going on.  Pick a unique name.

Comment: Yep forgot to add the return function. I changed the example. Apologies.

Comment: @MagicLasso - that's a pain.  I diagnose your issue and fully document it in a jsFiddle and then you change the code.  Anyway, I tried to add an answer about your changed code.

Comment: Hahaha sorry. I am building one in jsfiddle atm. So will the inner self be instantiated with new or...

Comment: @MagicLasso - I don't understand your question about the inner `self` (the one in `someFunc`).  That is created separately each time `obj.someFunc()` is called.  Because it is a more local scope than the outer one, it's definition will "hide" or "override" the higher level one and you will not be able to access the higher level `self` from within `someFunc()`.

Comment: Hmmm yea i worded that very poorly. I am wondering if I can constantly access the top level self even from within a closured function. Ive realized from testing on jsfiddle that i can without needing to pass self.

Comment: Then I decided to get convoluted and put in that inner self and try to find where it might be hiding.

Comment: @MagicLasso - see what I've added to my answer.  "Convoluted" is generally considered bad when it comes to software.  Avoid it.  Write simple to understand code.  Use more lines and more descriptive names when needed to make the code clear.  The structure you have in your question now is not what I would consider easy to understand or follow code.

Comment: THANKS! What you are saying makes complete sense. I had NO clue that closured functions inside would be run at instantiation. Really thought all closures where set at load time/run time/im bad with vernacular.

Comment: @MagicLasso - The outer function has `()` at the end of it.  It gets run at initialization because of the `()`.  The end result of running that function is to create the top level `var self = {...}` and to then return a function that is assigned to `var testClass`.  Because that function that is saved in `testClass` has access to the outer `var self`, a lasting closure is created.  It can't be garbage collected yet because there are still live references to the variables in that outer function.  That's what makes a closure.  A function scope that stll has live references to something in it.